# Setting {knitr} chunk options for references in {pkgdown} website

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pkgdown

Is there a way to to set the `{knitr}` chunk options for the examples created in a `{pkgdown}` website?

One of the things I'd like to avoid is messages and warnings being printed. In a normal Rmarkdown document I would create a chunk like this at the top.

```r
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```